# React.js "Yarn start" is running, but can't open the app in the browser

Tags: reactjs, yarnpkg, npx

I have a React application. I have installed the packages with `yarn` and ran it with `yarn start`. But, the app is not opening in the browser. The console shows me the following:

```
Compiled successfully!

You can now view extension in the browser.       

  http://localhost:3000

Note that the development build is not optimized.
To create a production build, use yarn build.    

webpack compiled successfully
Files successfully emitted, waiting for typecheck results...
Issues checking in progress...
No issues found.
```

But when I open the browser at `localhost:3000` and it shows nothing, but:

```
This site can’t be reached
localhost refused to connect.
```

Did anyone have this kind of issue? Any kind of help would be appreciated.

PS: I tried to remove `node_modules` and install packages again, `npx clear-npx-cache` as well, but nothing worked.

**Update**
After I build the app with `yarn build` and run `serve -s build` then I can access the app on `localhost:3000`. Why this happens?

Comment: What does `yarn start` do?

Comment: I added the console output to the question. When I run `yarn build` it builds successfully.

Comment: Yarn commands are defined in the `package.json`. We can't know what your what your particular `yarn start` do

Comment: "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have used

> ```
> yarn create react-app my-app
> ```

It will look like this.

> [image: Terminal]

The `package.json` will look like

> [image: package.json]

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried with `"PORT=3000 react-scripts start"` in your `"start"` script? You could actually try with any other port like `"PORT=3001 react-scripts start"` and see if that fixes the problem.

Comment: This doesn't fix my issue, but it might be useful for others!

Comment: @DreamBold thank you! - but sorry to hear it didn't fix your issue :)